# Drawing a line given the angle and a point on the line

Tags: python, image, opencv, geometry, augmented-reality

In my image I have a triangle (representing an arrow). This arrow defines the direction and area under consideration for further search in same image. For example if I have a triangle rotated at 30 degree w.r.t x-axis and it's tip is located at (250,150) in the image. I would want to find and draw a line normal the tip of triangle, as shown in the image below.

[image: Arrow and the Normal to it's tip]

In the image above, I have the angle of blue line in the triangle, to which the normal is to be drawn. Also the tip of the triangle is known which is the only point known on the normal line.

My code for the python function is given below. This code draws a line, passing through the tip but not necessarily NORMAL to the blue line.

```
def draw_intercepts(img,triangle):
    tip=triangle["tip"]
    x1=tip[0]
    y1=tip[1]
    arrow_angle=triangle["arrow_angle"]
    y_intercept=int(y1+((1/np.tan(arrow_angle))*x1))
    x_intercept=int(x1+(np.tan(arrow_angle)*y1))
    cv2.line(img,(x_intercept,0),(0,y_intercept),[0,0,255],3,cv2.LINE_AA)
```

This code is written by following an answer to this post: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381119/how-to-find-slope-x-and-y-intercepts-given-angle-to-the-normal-vector-and-a-poi

Note:
I updated the code as recommended:

```
def draw_intercepts(img,triangle):
    tip=triangle["tip"]
    x1=tip[0]
    y1=tip[1]
    arrow_angle=triangle["arrow_angle"]
    arrow_angle_rad=np.radians(arrow_angle)
    y_intercept=int(y1+((1/np.tan(arrow_angle_rad))*x1))
    x_intercept=int(x1+(np.tan(arrow_angle_rad)*y1))
    cv2.line(img, (x_intercept, 0), (0, y_intercept), [0, 0, 255], 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

This resolved the issue.
Now the line is drawn perfectly when the arrow_angle is in 1st or 3rd quadrant e.g. 0 < arrow_angle < 90 and 180 < arrow_angle < 270 but in 2nd and 4th quadrant ( 90 < arrow_angle < 180 and 270 < arrow_angle < 360) line angle is not drawn as correct angle or position. Even I don't know it line is drawn somewhere because it is not visible in image.

Comment: Did you convert the angle in radians before using `np.tan()`?

Comment: no, I provided the angle in degrees. Let me try that.

Comment: There is `np.radians()` to help you.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks @Gribouillis, I have updated the code in question. Yes it worked partially. It works in 1st and 3rd quadrant but demonstrates unknown behavior in 2nd and 4th quadrant.

Comment: The tangent function has nasty infinities; I would recommend that you use MBo's method, of cos and sin instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that used line equation "in intercept segments" is not universal - does not work for horizontal and vertical lines. With intercept approach cases 0, Pi/2, Pi, 3*Pi/2 or -Pi/2 must be treated separately.

If you `arrow_angle` is for blue line:

```
c = -Sin(arrow_angle)
s = Cos(arrow_angle)
```

If you `arrow_angle` is for red line:

```
c = Cos(arrow_angle)
s = Sin(arrow_angle)
```

Then draw line through points

```
 (x1 - c * 4096, y1  - s * 4096) and (x1 + c * 4096, y1  + s * 4096)
```

(I used arbitrary large constant comparable with screen size)

Comment: @Gribouillis  But using non-general equation for point finding is wrong way - it can cause errors/exceptions.

Comment: Yes it's true. Your formula looks good  but I don't have experience in opencv, why the 4096 ? You could alternatively compute the intercepts in all the cases.

Comment: @Gribouillis because the OP didn't specify the length of red line, he just used some large constant which ensures that the line would span the entire screen

Comment: @MBo You are right. I'm also having problems with horizontal or vertical lines when one of the intercepts are found at infinity. 
Well I have the "arrow_angle" for blue line and I want to use it to draw the red line. Does your answer represents same scenario?

Comment: @Gribouillis  4096 is arbitrary value. OpenCV will cut line:`The line is clipped by the image boundaries`  There is no intercept with vertical axis if line is vertical (Pi/2) and no intercept with horizontal axis for horizontal line (angle 0/Pi). With intercept approach these cases must be treated separately (author does not do this).

Comment: @Muhammad Abdullah  Yes, first c/s pair is for this case

Comment: Thank you @MBo. It worked perfectly.

Now that I have a line (starting and ending point), I want to write a function that take these points, arrow angle and a test point as input and returns if test point is beyond red line in the direction of arrow. 
e.g.

Angle = 180: True if point is to the left of the line, false otherwise
Angle = 0: True if point is to the right of the line, false otherwise
0 < Angle < 180: True if point is below the line, false otherwise
180 < Angle < 360: True if point is above the line, false otherwise

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah your function is scalar product `c * (x - x1) + s * (y - y1) > 0`

Comment: @Gribouillis I have posted another question for this problem, please look at this too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505032

Meanwhile I'll try to understand what you suggested here.